# Как достать переменную из списка?

Tags: python, словари

Есть список:

```
{'count': 4251, 'items': [{'date': 1661434300, 'from_id': 919863387, 'id': 854808, 'out': 0, 'attachments': [], 'conversation_message_id': 1270, 'fwd_messages': [], 'important': False, 'is_hidden': False, 'peer_id': 919863387, 'random_id': 0, 'text': 'привет'}]}
```

Из этого списка нужно достать переменную 'text'.

Comment: Это не список, это словарь. что именно у вас не получается?

Comment: ['items'][0]['text']

Comment: @strawdog, извините, перепутал!

Comment: @СергейШ, спасибо! Помогло!